# Get same data from 2 different tables and join it with 3rd table in DB2

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have a special situation. I can do it by writing a program, but I would prefer to do it by writing a query.. Any suggestion/answer on this query will be very helpful.

So, here is my requirement..

I have 4 different tables.

Table1:

```
plan_id  lob_cd col3 col4 col5..... 
1000     1010    c1   d1   e1
ABBB     1020    C2   D2   E2
ABAB     1020    C3   D3   E3
```

Table2:

```
plan_id network_id  cl1 cl2 cl3.... 
1000        20       c1  d1  e1
ABAB        21       C2  D2  E2
```

Table3:

```
LOB_cd network_id  cc1  cc2 cc3.... 
1010      30        c1   d1  e1 
1020      40        c2   d2  e2
```

Table4:

```
netowrk_id  network_desc  coll1  coll2.... 
20            test desc1    xxx    yyyy
21            test desc2    yyy     xzzzz 
30            desc3         sffd   sfsf
40            desc4          sff    wewr
50            desc5        sfsf     sfsfsf
```

Now, I need following details out of all these 4 tables.

Result data:

```
Plan_id  LOB_cd netwrok_ID  network_desc  col3 col4 col5..... 
1000      1010  20           test desc1   c1    d1    e1 
ABBB      1020  21           test desc2   c2    d2    e2
ABAB      1020  40           desc4        c3    d3    e3
```

Here is the point.. I need network id from table2 first by using plan_id, if its present then I will use it and will get the network descrption from table 4 using network id. If plan id is not present in table2, then I need to check table3 using LOB cd to get network id and then join table4 to get network description.

If a record is present in both table 2 and table3, then table2 network id needs to be selected only.

Is it possible by writing any complex query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
select
    a.plan_id,
    a.lob_cd,
    coalesce(b.network_id, c.network_id) as network_id,
    d.network_desc,
    a.col3,
    a.col4,
    a.col5
from table1 a
left join table2 b
    on a.plan_id = b.plan_id
left join table3 c
    on a.lob_cd = c.lob_cd
left join table4 d
    on coalesce(b.network_id, c.network_id) = d.network_id
```

Comment: Thanks Mackers, got the idea how to combine network id from 2 different table, but since plan id ABAB is present in table2 and corresponding lob code is present in table3, This leads to duplicate rows in final result... also, this query is trying to get the network id from both the table. Is there anything to stop if we got the network id from table2 first ?

Comment: @PrasantaPradhan can you double check that the data is correct in your schema and results? Your results have row 3 with values of "c3," "d3," and "e3;" however, none of the source tables have these values.

Comment: @PrasantaPradhan to answer the question in your comment directly, the coalesce function will pull the value of network_id from table2, if it finds a value, it will use that value from table2, otherwise it falls back on the network id value from table 3. So in essence, it "stops" if we have the value from table 2 first.

Comment: Thanks Mackers. your answer is correct.. I was getting multiple rows in result because there was multiple rows in table3. Thank you.